# Loading data from SQL Server to pentaho BI Reports

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

I have encountered an issue in Pentaho-bi-ce, I have created a report in designer and published the report successfully on BI server v3.9.0 community edition. while on report designer I see the output, but on user-console nothing is presented. I have configured the JDBC and database connection but still no changes.

Something else is that I don't see anything event static texts in PDF output format.

thanks in prior

A.H.

Comment: Check your logs - catalina.out and Pentaho.log.  Then if you're still stuck, post the errors from those logs here.  If you find the answer, then answer your own question.

Comment: @Codek thanks. It was a problem with version mismatch.